# How can i add more context menus and commands to the shell file extensions?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenu

What i tried to do is to add this part to the Program.cs

```
const string MenuText1 = "List all images";
```

Then

```
FileShellExtension.Register(Program.FileType,
                    Program.KeyName, Program.MenuText1,
                    menuCommand);
```

The problem now is that i see in the context menu only the second menu the MenuText1 but not the MenuText, and I wanted to see them both and also the MenuText1 when i click on it it's doing the same command as the MenuText. I want to add more MenuTexts and more commands so each new MenuText1..2..3..4..5 will have his own command.

This is the FileShellExtension class code

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace SimpleContextMenu
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Register and unregister simple shell context menus.
    /// </summary>
    static class FileShellExtension
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Register a simple shell context menu.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileType">The file type to register.</param>
        /// <param name="shellKeyName">Name that appears in the registry.</param>
        /// <param name="menuText">Text that appears in the context menu.</param>
        /// <param name="menuCommand">Command line that is executed.</param>
        public static void Register(
            string fileType, string shellKeyName, 
            string menuText, string menuCommand)
        {
            Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileType) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(shellKeyName) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuText) && 
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuCommand));

            // create full path to registry location
            string regPath = string.Format(@"{0}\shell\{1}", fileType, shellKeyName);

            // add context menu to the registry
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(regPath))
            {
                key.SetValue(null, menuText);
            }

            // add command that is invoked to the registry
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(
                string.Format(@"{0}\command", regPath)))
            {               
                key.SetValue(null, menuCommand);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Unregister a simple shell context menu.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileType">The file type to unregister.</param>
        /// <param name="shellKeyName">Name that was registered in the registry.</param>
        public static void Unregister(string fileType, string shellKeyName)
        {
            Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileType) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(shellKeyName));

            // full path to the registry location           
            string regPath = string.Format(@"{0}\shell\{1}", fileType, shellKeyName);

            // remove context menu from the registry
            Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKeyTree(regPath);
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
namespace SimpleContextMenu
{
    static class Program
    {
        // file type to register
        const string FileType = "jpegfile";

        // context menu name in the registry
        const string KeyName = "Simple Context Menu";

        // context menu text
        const string MenuText = "Copy to Grayscale";
        const string MenuText1 = "List all images";

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // process register or unregister commands
            if (!ProcessCommand(args))
            {
                // invoked from shell, process the selected file
                CopyGrayscaleImage(args[0]);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Process command line actions (register or unregister).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">Command line arguments.</param>
        /// <returns>True if processed an action in the command line.</returns>
        static bool ProcessCommand(string[] args)
        {
            // register
            if (args.Length == 0 || string.Compare(args[0], "-register", true) == 0)
            {
                // full path to self, %L is placeholder for selected file
                string menuCommand = string.Format(
                    "\"{0}\" \"%L\"", Application.ExecutablePath);

                // register the context menu
                FileShellExtension.Register(Program.FileType,
                    Program.KeyName, Program.MenuText,
                    menuCommand);

                FileShellExtension.Register(Program.FileType,
                    Program.KeyName, Program.MenuText1,
                    menuCommand);

                MessageBox.Show(string.Format(
                    "The {0} shell extension was registered.",
                    Program.KeyName), Program.KeyName);

                return true;
            }

            // unregister       
            if (string.Compare(args[0], "-unregister", true) == 0)
            {
                // unregister the context menu
                FileShellExtension.Unregister(Program.FileType, Program.KeyName);

                MessageBox.Show(string.Format(
                    "The {0} shell extension was unregistered.",
                    Program.KeyName), Program.KeyName);

                return true;
            }

            // command line did not contain an action
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Make a grayscale copy of the image.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filePath">Full path to the image to copy.</param>
        static void CopyGrayscaleImage(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                // full path to the grayscale copy
                string grayFilePath = Path.Combine(
                    Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath),
                    string.Format("{0} (grayscale){1}",
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath),
                    Path.GetExtension(filePath)));

                // using calls Dispose on the objects, important 
                // so the file is not locked when the app terminates
                using (Image image = new Bitmap(filePath))
                using (Bitmap grayImage = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height))
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(grayImage))
                {
                    // setup grayscale matrix
                    ImageAttributes attr = new ImageAttributes();
                    attr.SetColorMatrix(new ColorMatrix(new float[][]{   
                        new float[]{0.3086F,0.3086F,0.3086F,0,0},
                        new float[]{0.6094F,0.6094F,0.6094F,0,0},
                        new float[]{0.082F,0.082F,0.082F,0,0},
                        new float[]{0,0,0,1,0,0},
                        new float[]{0,0,0,0,1,0},
                        new float[]{0,0,0,0,0,1}}));

                    // create the grayscale image
                    g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
                        0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attr);

                    // save to the file system
                    grayImage.Save(grayFilePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                    // success
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Copied grayscale image {0}", grayFilePath), Program.KeyName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("An error occurred: {0}", ex.Message), Program.KeyName);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, why the 2nd item `List all images` overwrites the first `Copy to Grayscale` after registration?

Let's open the registry editor to examine the registry settings.

You can see that the second parameter to the `FileShellExtension.Register` method, which is `Program.KeyName` in this case, is mapped to a **Registry Key** under `jpegfile/shell`.

So if you want to register 2 menu items, you need to provide 2 different strings as the shell key name. Like "Simple Context Menu" and "Another Context Menu".

[image: Registry keys after registering context menu]

Comment: kennyzx this is working fine. What about the command now ? CopyGrayscaleImage(args[0]); this part will work for this command only. I mean both context menus "Copy to Grayscale" and "List all images" will execute the same command this: CopyGrayscaleImage(args[0]); but if i want to add a specific command for "List all images" ? Another command for "List all images". Now when i click on "List all images" it will also make this CopyGrayscaleImage.

Comment: Modify this line `string menuCommand = string.Format(`, . now it only contains the full path to the selected item, add another parameter. Like `string menuCommand = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"%L\" CopyGrayscaleImage", Application.ExecutablePath);` so you can decide what to call in the Main method.

Comment: I tried this: string menuCommand = string.Format("\"{0}\"{1}\" \"%L\" CopyGrayscaleImage", " List", Application.ExecutablePath); but it's not working i guess i'm wrong. So i ried like yours string menuCommand = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"%L\" CopyGrayscaleImage", Application.ExecutablePath); but then i'm not using another command. Could you show me please how to work with this line and how ot use it in the Main method ? Maybe in the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Pls. ask another question, since the discussion is hard to follow by others. The question and answer should also be helpful to other readers.

Comment: Added a new question to make it more clear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113985/how-can-i-add-more-commands-to-the-shell-file-extensions